# Prevent iphone email client from zooming responsive emails

Tags: ios, email, outlook, responsive-design

I have a requirement which needs me to send a **responsive email from outlook to other outlook users** within the organization. I coded the template using antworts email template and when we tested it, the results were as follows

1. An outlook account when accessed in **Iphones default email client ignores the media queries** and instead just shows in the **zoomed in version**
2. When the email is opened in gmail,the responsive version is shown.

I am confused about whether the outlook exchange server is stripping out the media queries when viewed by iphone or its just some code I need to add to ensure the iphone email does not show the content as zoomed in.

Any inputs would be appreciated

Comment: Have you added the `viewport` meta tag to your email markup?

Comment: No,thats the first thing I checked.

Comment: Is that "No, I've not added it" or "No, I added it and it had no effect"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook messes up your original code by converting it to 'Microsoft Word HTML', as Outlook is notorious for using the MS Word engine to render html email. You'll notice `<p>` tags everywhere and parts of your code missing. Designing an email that will be forwarded is very tricky and most email designers don't even bother attempting it. Personally, I do, but only with static fixed width layouts.

Some exchange servers are known to strip media queries, so that is a possibility also. To find out exactly what is happening, you'll need to see the code that arrives in each client. Not sure how to do this in an iPhone, but you can view page element in gmail/chrome (or use Litmus Scope) and Outlook also allows you to view email source.

[Litmus Scope](https://litmus.com/scope/) is a handy email tool that allows you to view the email and code as received in Gmail.